# Ubuntu 23.03 Gnome dump

Tags: gnome

I have HP ENVY x360 ml laptop with 16 GB memory. installed ubuntu 23.04 now after unlocking laptop got gnome shell dump error.

Have thesefiles:

Do i need to reinstall ubuntu or go back to Pop -OS as was the last OS

```
sastrymv@sastrymv-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:/var/crash$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 23.04
Release: 23.04
Codename: lunar
```

```
sastrymv@sastrymv-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:/var/crash$ ls -ltr
total 2654
-rw-r----- 1 sastrymv whoopsie 2756156 Apr 28 11:10 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sastrymv sastrymv 0 Apr 28 11:10 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie 37 Apr 28 11:10 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 sastrymv whoopsie 227473 May 5 11:18 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sastrymv sastrymv 0 May 5 11:18 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie 37 May 5 11:18 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: Ignore the crash files in `/var/crash` for a moment. What is actually happening when you boot up and login to the system? Do you get a graphical desktop? Please explain what's actually happening.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting